# Elastic search error in magento 2.4.3 ((code=killed, signal=KILL))

Tags: magento2, catalog, catalogsearch, elasticsearch, reindexing

when i check the the elasitcsearch status using this command :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch status
```

i got this:

```
elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: signal) since Thu 2022-05-26 07:23:14 UTC; 27min ago
       Docs: https://www.elastic.co
    Process: 31353 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/systemd-entrypoint -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet (code=killed, signal=KILL)
   Main PID: 31353 (code=killed, signal=KILL)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 4691)
     Memory: 6.6M
     CGroup: /system.slice/elasticsearch.service

May 26 07:22:38 ip-172-31-16-124 systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
May 26 07:22:59 ip-172-31-16-124 systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
May 26 07:23:14 ip-172-31-16-124 systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
May 26 07:23:14 ip-172-31-16-124 systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
```

the elasticsearch information :

[image]

how can i solve this problem؟

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this command in your project root directory.

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart elasticsearch
```

and if this doesn't work, try restarting your system
and if that doesn't work, try

run this command in terminal

sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options

```
-Xms4g
-Xmx4g
```

and change this value according to your RAM,
if 16 GB ram then set value half of your ram number

```
-Xms8g
-Xmx8g
```

Comment: after changing the value in this file run the above command again.

Comment: it worked thank you very much

Comment: please accepts my answer, thanks

Comment: spent 3 days and you resolved it within 3 seconds, love from me